# How to regex rotate properties from transform value

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-transforms

Let's say I have a css transform property that looks like this:

```
scale(1.02, 2.0) rotateX(50) rotateY(20) rotateZ(10) skew(100deg)
```

I need to remove the substring `rotateX(50) rotateY(20) rotateZ(10)` from the property AND get the 3 values `50`, `20`, and `10` as an array

How would you do this using javascript?

Comment: The correct syntax for CSS transform should be `scale(1.02, 2.0) rotateX(50deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(10deg) skew(100deg)`. None of the answers will work with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```js
var txt = 'scale(1.02, 2.0) rotateX(50) rotateY(20) rotateZ(10) skew(100deg)';

var array = txt.match(/\(\d+(?=\))/g).map(function(x){return x.slice(1)});
document.write(array);

var new_text = txt.replace(/\).* /, ') ');
document.write('<br>' + new_text);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The correct syntax for CSS transform should be `scale(1.02, 2.0) rotateX(50deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(10deg) skew(100deg)` and your code will then fail...

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex `rotateX\((\d+)\)\s+rotateY\((\d+)\)\s+rotateZ\((\d+)\)`;

```
var transform = 'scale(1.02, 2.0) rotateX(50) rotateY(20) rotateZ(10) skew(100deg)';
var match = transform.match(/rotateX\((\d+)\)\s+rotateY\((\d+)\)\s+rotateZ\((\d+)\)/);
var arr = match.slice(1, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use 3 separate RegExp so it will work no matter the order of the rotate
statements. This example uses ES6 [destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)
for brevity but you could easily write it in ES5 using a temporary variable to
hold the `.match` results.

```
var transformString = 'scale(1.02, 2.0) rotateX(50) rotateY(20) rotateZ(10) skew(100deg)';

// The first variable receives the entire match which we will later remove from
// transformString. The second variable receives the match group, the numeric
// value inside the parentheses 
var [xText, xValue] = transformString.match(/\srotateX\((\d+)\)/i);
var [yText, yValue] = transformString.match(/\srotateY\((\d+)\)/i);
var [zText, zValue] = transformString.match(/\srotateZ\((\d+)\)/i);

// remove rotate commands
[xText, yText, zText].forEach(function (text) {
  transformString = transformString.replace(text, '');
});
var values = [xValue, yValue, zValue];
console.log(transformString, values);
```

Note that the numbers we captured are string representations of those numbers, not actual numbers. If you need them to be numbers you could use `.map` to convert them to numbers.

```
values = values.map(function (n) {
  return +n;
});
```